# How to make bots to learn from experience

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, genetic-algorithm, bots

I am writing bot for one rts game.

I am using fuzzy logic to evaluate current position (mine and enemies') and to issue commands.

I have couple fuzzy variables: `military_buildings`, `civilian_building`, `army_power`, `enemy_power` and `distance`. I also have couple fuzzy linguistic values like `VERY_GOOD`, `GOOD`, `NORMAL`, `BAD`, `VERY_BAD`.

My next task is to make bots to learn, to avoid to all behave on same way. Any advice or idea how to solve this?

To use GA for tuning parameters (but I don't know ratings of players so I don't know if bot wins over a weak player or loses to a strong player).

Does anyone have experience with similar problems (I can change implementation and replace fuzzy logic if there is easier way to learn bots from experience)?

Comment: What exactly do you want to learn?

Comment: Applying GA to a strategy game, wouldn't one typically play members of a generation against one another in order to rank them? In general though, I'm not sure exactly what your approach is.

Comment: What experience would the bots learn from if they don't have access to any kind of player ratings?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at reinforcement learning. Here are [a quick preview](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Reinforcement_learning) and [a book](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/the-book.html) that can help you.

Based on your description, this is what I'd use :)

Answer (score 2):

The idea of using GAs to tune the parameters to Fuzzy Linguistic Variables is a good one (I wish I thought of it!); the fuzzy logic gives you a nice continuous response curve while the GA will search through a large solution space. I think it's definitely a strategy worth pursuing; you should write up your results.

Comment: GA has already been applied in the field of FL, eg: 
1) C.-A. Peña-Reyes and M. Sipper, Fuzzy CoCo: Balancing accuracy and interpretability of fuzzy models by means of coevolution, in Accuracy Improvements in Linguistic Fuzzy Modeling, J. Casillas, O. Cordón, F. Herrera, and L. Magdalena, Eds., vol. 129 of Studies in Fuzziness and Soft Computing, chapter 6, pp. 119-146. Springer-Verlag, Heidelberg, 2003.
2) C.-A. Peña-Reyes and M. Sipper, Fuzzy CoCo: A cooperative-coevolutionary approach to fuzzy modeling, IEEE Transactions on Fuzzy Systems, vol. 9, no. 5, pp. 727-737, October 2001.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Thanks for those links.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would look at the AIIDE annual Starcraft Competition, it is sponsored in part by AAAI so there are some really high quality approaches to this problem. In particular if you are concerned with higher-level reasoning like resource management etc. [Starcraft Competition Site](http://www.aiide.org/starcraft-competition) Also, the competitors source code is all available open source so if you want to check out some other techniques I recommend it. FYI, most of the top competitors for this type of problem have historically used some variant of a Probabilistic State Machine [Paper on Probabilistic FSMs](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/inf1/cl/notes/Comp7.pdf), so this may make a good test bed for parameter tuning. FYI this is also the approach that some of the top Game AI middleware software uses for Game AI, like XAIT.